# GTM Google Tag Manager How To Track Date Picker Values

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How to enable Google Tag Manager to track the dates selected on the date picker?
Currently, with Form Text, I am able to capture the day selected such as '21' or '30'. 
But I want GTM to capture the entire date such as '3/21/19' or '3/30/19'.
How to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example of the date picker?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can capture the date, month and year individually, you can just reference then together in GTM.

Example if you have variable names "myDate", "myMonth" & "myYear":

You can just combine them together by referencing them by "{{myDate}}/{{myMonth}}/{{myYear}}"

Use without quotes. Place it in any field in GTM tags (either custom dimension or event, etc)